# Trying to add search svg in input box

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to add svg in input box , but its not showing. I am using third party library for autocomplete("ng-autocomplete") but not able to apply css on that .

Please kindly let me know if we can add svg ?

[svg sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tidq88?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.css)

Answer (score 0):

The actual input element has a background color which is blocking the background-image that you added to its container. Either add:

```
background-color: transparent
```

...to the `input`, or move the background image css to target the input directly.

Comment: I cant move it directly there because its third party package and i dont want to do direct changes there.

Comment: I am talking about writing new rules in CSS to target the elements, not moving HTML